# NotificationCompat Builder error

Tags: android

I am facing an issue in building a Notification for my media player. Basically I am trying to build remote controls for my media player using Notification builder. I am using NotificationCompat Library to support lower version of android. Below is the part of the code which is facing error :

```
private NotificationCompat.Action createAction(int iconResId, String title, String action){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicBoxService.class);
    intent.setAction(action);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainApplication.getContext(), 1, intent, 0);
    return new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(iconResId, title, pendingIntent).build();
}

private void updateNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Action playPauseAction = playbackState.getState() == playbackState.STATE_PLAYING ?
            createAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_18dp, "Pause", ACTION_PAUSE):
            createAction(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_18dp, "Play", ACTION_PLAY);

    NotificationCompat notificationCompat = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_TRANSPORT)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(artist)
            .setOngoing(playbackState.getState() == playbackState.STATE_PLAYING)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music_box_black_18dp)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .addAction(createAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_previous_black_18dp, "Previous", ACTION_PREV))
            .addAction(playPauseAction)
            .addAction(createAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_next_black_18dp, "Next", ACTION_NEXT))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(mMediaSession.getSessionToken()).setShowActionsInCompactView(1,2))
                    .build();
    ((NotificationManagerCompat)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(1, notificationCompat);
}
```

Here  is the screenshot of the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfMyc.png)

The thing is that changing the line NotificationCompat notificationCompat = new ... to Notification notificationCompat = new .. solves the error, but I am not sure whether that is correct.

Android Studio gives the error:
required: android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat
Found: android.app.Notification

Thanks!
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NotificationCompat` is just used for building the `Notification`. Building a notification using `NotificationCompat.Builder` still returns an `android.app.Notification`, not a `NotificationCompat`. Just change your declaration of `notificationCompat` to be:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        ...
        .build();
```

Comment: I found that on my own, just wasn't sure whether that was correct. Thanks for the help!!!